My website is in laravel 11 but it is not working on live server hostinger


I tried everything like adding .htaccess file in public_html so that it access public/ folder or change location of index.php but this error is not solving.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This error is for blade, it shows that laravel is loaded, but it is having trouble finding the view, please make sure that the Bharat.Home path is there, also be careful to use lowercase and uppercase words in the view.
UPDATE:
If you are running the project on the host, you can create a path in web.php like this:
Route::get('optimize', function(){
    Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
    Artisan::call('optimize');

    return 'optimized';
});

and run the path in the browser so that it will be displayed optimized

There is Home file in folder Bharat With correct case I checked but route not finding path

please run command php artisan optimize:clear and php artisan optimize and try again test

Where this command should I run in hostinger server
